# True or false? Let $f:M \longrightarrow N $ map $C^{\infty}$ bijective, then $f$ is a diffeomorphism.

Tags: geometry, manifolds

True or false?
Let $f:M \longrightarrow N $ map $C^{\infty}$ bijective, where $M$ and $N$ are manifolds de class $C^{\infty}$, then $f$ is a diffeomorphism.

**Comments:**

I am thinking of making a restriction on the function $\pi: S^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}P^n$, but I do not know if this works because it diffeomorphism local.

Comment: $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x)=x^3$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Yes!! Thank you.

Comment: It is true if you moreover assume that the derivative at each point is an invertible linear map.

Comment: In fact $M$ and $N$ do not need to be diffeomorphic. There is an example [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/41993/40804).